# Fixing "ExtLibUtil cannot be resolved" issue

Tags: java, xpages, lotus-notes, xpages-extlib

I have been working on trying to use the [openLogger](http://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/project.xsp?action=openDocument&name=XPages%20OpenLog%20Logger) tool which uses  [the OpenLog Database](http://www.openntf.org/projects/pmt.nsf/ProjectLookup/OpenLog) also available at openNTF, and I have hit a bit of a snag.  **My question is not about those databases explicitly, they are just a good example of what is going wrong!**

My issue is that I wanted to rebuild the OpenLogger Demo/test database after making a few changes to the xsp.properties file, and I suddenly was presented the wonderful gift of 12 or more errors, all of which were that the com.ibm.xsp.extlib.util.ExtLibUtil class could not be resolved.

After a bit of googling, I found out that it sometimes helps to re-install Designer - done (three times)
or to re-install the ExtLibs (done a few times and then upgraded to the 900_201305* version)
nothing.

I have really tried everything I can think of, and everything that I could find via google, but I cannot figure out how to get this thing to resolve.  I remember once upon a time having to copy specific jar files into the designer install directory, but I cannot remember the details, nor can I find anything about that, nor do I know if this is my issue.  I also thought about a specific designer variable not being set that would tell designer where to find the jar files, but I would not know where to begin searching for that.

Any help getting this thing to resolve would be a HUGE! help.  It could also be that I wish to use this awesome looking class in my own applications.  Thanks!

Comment: I assume you went through the Build Path and made sure it was exactly like the test database.  I found the snipping tool in windows very useful for comparing the build paths.  The package explorer is also your friend in comparing the two databases.

Comment: @SteveZavocki it is the demo/test database that is already not working for me.  It seems like this issue is a lot more me-specific than a problem with the database.  I am certain that designer is not finding a jar file, but I do not know how to diagnose or correct that problem.

Comment: Did you check the package statement, and make sure the jar is in the same folder?   Alternatively, you could change the package to fit where you put it.  (Although if that was the issue, it wouldn't/shouldn't compile.)

Comment: I managed to get it to work.  For some reason, I had to open up the xsp.properties again and uncheck/recheck the com.ibm.xsp.extlib.library dependancy.  I came across this idea after comparing two databases that had nothing to do with each other.  One had the correct jar referenced, the other didnt.  That way, I knew that it was not an issue with my particular installation.  I would not have thought of it without your comments.  THANK YOU!

Comment: Glad to help.  I will go ahead and string together an answer so that it doesn't stay out here unanswered.  Go ahead and clarify what I say so that it helps others who find this later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make sure that the jar files is found and able to be used, try these things:

- Use the package explorer to make sure the jar is in the "Referenced Libraries" folder
- Check the build path, and add the jar to the build path if necessary
- Examine the XSP properties file and make sure it looks correct, and then change something and resave it
- Use Project | Clean which sometimes fixes issues like this

Comment: I would add, in Designer, go to File/Application/Application Management.  Open the section that says IBM\NOtes\Data\workspace\applications......... and make sure that all of the Extension Library components are installed.  If there are only two, that is not enough.  There should be like 7 or so. IF there are not, then the ExtLibs are not correctly installed and you should open a new SO question so we can discuss it.